# How does one know exact pixel size / relationships between CSS elements?

Tags: css, pixel, mockups

I'm diving into CSS in an effort to be more well-rounded.  I'm currently reading "Designing with Web Standards" which is great so far.

My question is, when you get a mockup in PSDs, how do you know the exact pixel dimensions of backgrounds, images, various blocks/divs, font-sizes, etc?

I'll most likely be using Photoshop to work with files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photoshop has a grid tool and rulers. You can measure it there. It's pretty accurate.
take a look at this img.

`these are inches by the way, you can change it to pixels.`

[image]

Comment: Also, the "Info" window can be used to read the dimension and location attributes of an element.